# How to config properly a subdomain ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, subdomain

I have an application using ASP.NET MVC to manage (CMS) the main website application.

I'd like to user the subdomain cms.example.com to run this application.

But when I access cms.example.com, it redirects to cms.example.com/CMS/Account/Login.

And when I try to log in, it not works. But if, a access example.com/cms, everything works fine.

On my main domain (example.com), I have another ASP.NET MVC application.

What can I do to my subdomian application works properly?

Many thanks.

Comment: Is the example.com/CMS a completely different MVC project than example.com?

Comment: Yes, it is. They share a common library, but are differenct projects.

Comment: besides setting the subdomain headers in your webserver, have you done something for dns resolution?

Answer (score 1):

The CMS app shouldn't be located inside the main app, but in a directory of it's own. On IIS you create a new website bound to cms.example.com, rooted at the CMS app directory. That way both apps use their own domain, and do not interfere with each other. If both apps share some libraries you have to copy them to each application directory, or put them in the GAC.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using a shared hosting and haven't access to IIS. But I guess my hosting was created a virtual directory for the CMS app. Thanks.

Comment: @MCardinale: do you have access to a control panel where you can create additional websites, or are you restricted to only one website?